# What are the specific jars I need to bundle with my application to be able to run JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I've built a swing app that uses JasperReports. I've been bundling all the jars that JasperReports comes with which makes up the majority of my install file.

Can I just include jasperreports-4.1.2.jar, or do i really need all the extra jars to be able to run my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need these files:
jasperreports-4.1.2/dist/jasperreports-4.1.2.jar
jasperreports-4.1.2/dist/jasperreports-applet-4.1.2.jar
jasperreports-4.1.2/dist/jasperreports-fonts-4.1.2.jar
jasperreports-4.1.2/dist/jasperreports-javaflow-4.1.2.jar
(You can get rid of the fonts jar if you do not use the DejaVu font.)

There are 54 jars in jasperreports-4.1.2/lib
You surely don't need them all. You only need... the ones that you use. But there is no simple answer to which ones you need.

If you never use groovy in your reports, then you'll be fine without groovy-all-1.7.5.jar. If you never generate PDFs, then you'll be fine without iText. If you have no charts, then you won't miss jfreechart. The barbecue lib is used only if you generate bar codes. Et cetera.

Of course in one sense it's safest to ship them all. Then you cannot be missing anything. But if you're certain about not needing certain features, then just include the ones you need. Some are obvious, but not all of them are.

Sorry, but there's no simpler answer. Maybe sort by size, get rid of some of the bigger ones, and then test to be sure you didn't break anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need most if not all of the jars bundled with jasper reports distribution